Nested list in Python - Transpose nested list
I have a below nested list:
list = [Language:'Tamil'
        Capital: 'Chennai' 
        Place: 'Chennai', 'Vellore', 'Trichy', 'Madurai' 
]

I'm expecting to transpose it as:
Language     Capital     Place
Tamil        Chennai     Chennai
Tamil        Chennai     Vellore
Tamil        Chennai     Trichy
Tamil        Chennai     Madurai 

Tried converting to pandas dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(list)

The result is
Language    Capital       Place  
Tamil       Chennai       ['Chennai', 'Vellore', 'Trichy', 'Madurai']  

How can I transpose each list of values in a new row for the place?

The first item in your question is by no means a "list". It maybe a dictionary where the last item has a list as a value. Could you please eidt the post so that it is syntactically correct?

(the way Python will output your data structure if you just print it out will suffice)

It is a list of dictionary, type of that class is a list

Your example data doesn't look like a list of dictionaries. Your intended output is also unclear. Please edit your question so that both input and intended output are valid Python literals.

First:
data = {
    'Language': 'Tamil',
    'Capital': 'Chennai',
    'Place': ['Chennai', 'Vellore', 'Trichy', 'Madurai']
}

Next, you can create a DataFrame by repeating the values for Language and Capital and expanding the Place list into multiple rows:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Language': [data['Language']] * len(data['Place']),
    'Capital': [data['Capital']] * len(data['Place']),
    'Place': data['Place']
})

Output:
     Language  Capital    Place
0    Tamil     Chennai    Chennai
1    Tamil     Chennai    Vellore
2    Tamil     Chennai    Trichy
3    Tamil     Chennai    Madurai


from itertools import product

data = {
    "Language": "Tamil",
    "Capital": "Chennai",
    "Place": ["Chennai", "Vellore", "Trichy", "Madurai"]
}

results = list(product([data["Language"]], [data["Capital"]], data["Place"]))

for result in results:
    print(f'{result[0]: <10} {result[1]: <10} {result[2]}')


Assuming this input and that you want to convert to pandas DataFrame:
data = {
    'Language': 'Tamil',
    'Capital': 'Chennai',
    'Place': ['Chennai', 'Vellore', 'Trichy', 'Madurai']
}

If you know the key that contains the list, just explode it:
import pandas as pd

out = pd.DataFrame(data).explode('Place')

If you want to programmatically identify the keys that contain lists:
from itertools import product

out = pd.DataFrame(product(*(v if isinstance(v, list) else [v]
                             for v in data.values())),
                   columns=data
                  )

Output:
  Language  Capital    Place
0    Tamil  Chennai  Chennai
1    Tamil  Chennai  Vellore
2    Tamil  Chennai   Trichy
3    Tamil  Chennai  Madurai

